# push does not works inside if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have the code below, but `items.push` does not work when it is inside the `if` statement. If uncomment the line before ending `}` then `items.push` works as expected.

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
    row = resultexpense.rows.item(i);

    t.executeSql('SELECT * FROM expensepayments WHERE Barcode = ?',
    [row.barcode], 
        function(t, resultpaid) {
            var myrowpaid, 
                myrowpaidlen;
            myrowpaidlen = resultpaid.rows.length;
            alert(myrowpaidlen); //alerts 1
            if (myrowpaidlen > 0){
                myrowpaid = resultpaid.rows.item(0);
                alert(row.amount); //alerts 90
                alert(myrowpaid.Amount); //alerts 50
                if (row.amount > myrowpaid.Amount){
                    alert(row.amount- myrowpaid.Amount); //alerts 40
                    items.push('<li><a href="#displayexpense" data-description="' + row.description + '" data-buildingcode = "' + row.buildingcode + '" data-barcode="' + row.barcode + '" data-amount="' + row.amount + '" data-buildingaddress="' + row.buildingaddress + '">' + row.description + '</a></li>');
                }
            } else {
                items.push('<li><a href="#displayexpense" data-description="' + row.description + '" data-buildingcode = "' + row.buildingcode + '" data-barcode="' + row.barcode + '" data-amount="' + row.amount + '" data-buildingaddress="' + row.buildingaddress + '">' + row.description + '</a></li>');
            }

        });
//  items.push('<li><a href="#displayexpense" data-description="' + row.description + '" data-buildingcode = "' + row.buildingcode + '" data-barcode="' + row.barcode + '" data-amount="' + row.amount + '" data-buildingaddress="' + row.buildingaddress + '">' + row.description + '</a></li>');

}
```

Comment: The `executeSql()` call is **asynchronous**.  The code in the callback won't run until after the database responds, which will be *after* the entire loop has finished.

Comment: Also, you probably should have just edited your previous question, as it's the same thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in javascript loop (push to array does not work)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628321/error-in-javascript-loop-push-to-array-does-not-work)

Comment: so what is the correct syntax. Sorry but I am new in javascript

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what `typeof` your variable is, is it `number` or just a `string`?

if `typeof row.amount == "string"` or `typeof myrowpaid.Amount == "string"` then the `if` condition not going to execute.

to be sure, your variable is `number` type, use `parseInt()` function to convert into number

```
if (parseInt(row.amount, 10) > parseInt(myrowpaid.Amount, 10)){
                alert(row.amount- myrowpaid.Amount); //alerts 40
                items.push('<li><a href="#displayexpense" data-description="' + row.description + '" data-buildingcode = "' + row.buildingcode + '" data-barcode="' + row.barcode + '" data-amount="' + row.amount + '" data-buildingaddress="' + row.buildingaddress + '">' + row.description + '</a></li>');
            }
```

---

if you not already deceleared the `items` variable then, add `var items = [];` before use of items variable

Comment: There may be various problems, but the real issue is that he's trying to use the array before all the query callbacks have completed.

Comment: he is saying that the items.push works outside the if condition, so i think he may already declared the items variable as an array.

Comment: But this alert(row.amount- myrowpaid.Amount); alerts the correct result (40) so the two amount are numbers

Comment: @K.K yes but the updates to the list are being done *inside an asynchronous callback function.* The updates will not happen until the queries are finished.

Comment: @user1081978: what is the alert(row.amount + myrowpaid.Amount); says?

Comment: the alert(row.amount + myrowpaid.Amount); says 135